# How to disable Google Chrome (or Chromium) start page ads / promotions?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

When opening a start page in chrome, at the bottom-middle location there is this promotion from Google to "Use Family Link" and "Start your school year with a Google course". I don't have kids neither do I go to school.

I tried looking for available options in `chrome://flags` but couldn't find anythign that would look like it could disable this.

How can I disable these advertisements? My adblocker won't work on my start page unfortunately (it's disabled, probably for "security" reasons).

I tried downloading Chromium (sync) but it's still there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are so annoyed because of it(like me), you can open settings > Go to **On Startup** > Select **Open a specific page or set of pages** and set google.com or whatever you prefer.

But yes this way you cant access the shortcuts.

Comment: True, for now I did install an extension that displays its own new tab page. But I like the default one, except for that annoying thing at the bottom. I did find the code in "resources.pak" but editing it means that one would need to edit chrome.dll too. I'm curious if there is a normal maner in which this can be disabled.